# install wx-widgets is driving me insane on Yosemite

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2. As far as I know, wx-widgets were preinstalled on older versions on OS X (probably that's why google search doesn't help), but that's not the case anymore. I need to get started on a C++ project using wx-widgets, using any IDE (Eclipse, Codelite, or whatever is best). However, I simply cannot get wx-widgets to work. After a workaround I was able to compile on my machine wxWidgets-3.0.2. I called from terminal make and make install, but the libraries seem to not be correctly installed. Indeed, if I create a project on Codelite I get many "wx-config: Command not found" errors. Can someone help me to get me started on installing the libraries and creating a simple project that includes wx-widgets?

Answer (score 2):

I use `homebrew` which is installed by copying and pasting one line from [the homebrew website](http://brew.sh).

Then, the installation of wxWidgets is simplicity itself with:

```
brew install wxmac
```

Any problems, you just call the doctor with

```
brew doctor
```

Now you have a proper package manager you can install ImageMagick, GNU Parallel, GNU awk, Oxygen, webkit2html, zeromq, tree, SDL, Redis, sqlitebrowser, pandoc, exiftool, ffmpeg, 7zip, awscli, etc...

You can then compile your wxWidgets programs with

```
g++ `wx-config --cxxflags` -o sample sample.cpp `wx-config --libs`
```

Comment: That `wx-config --cxxflags` is such a sound idea.

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully compile and install wxWidgets on Yosemite with these commands:

```
- Get the latest sources of wxWidgets 3 from wxwidgets.org and unpack them.
- Move the unpacked directory someplace where you want to keep it.
- Open a terminal and change into the wxwidgets directory.
- Create two directories: build-release and build-debug (don't rename those!)
- Change into wxwidgets/build-release
- Run 
  ../configure --with-osx_cocoa --disable-shared --with-opengl --enable-universal-binary=i386,x86_64 --with-macosx-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk --with-macosx-version-min=10.6
- Run make, then sudo make install
- Change into wxwidgets/build-debug
- Run 
  ../configure --enable-debug --with-osx_cocoa --with-opengl --enable-universal-binary=i386,x86_64 --with-macosx-sdk=/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk --with-macosx-version-min=10.6
- Run make, then sudo make install
```

Be aware that these instructions are for compiling against the Mac OS X 10.6 SDK, which I have at `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk`. You can try to omit the --with-macosx-sdk parameter altogether, which will compile using the latest SDK. Also ensure that you have Xcode and the command line developer tools installed.

These commands will install static libraries for the release build and shared libraries for the debug build. You can change this by supplying or omitting the --disable-shared parameter.

Comment: I followed your instructions (except that I had to change a line in the original source code because otherwise it doesn't compile on my system since I don't have installed 10.6 SDK). It compiles with 3 warnings but 0 errors. Make and sudo make install seem to be ok too, but Codelite still tells me several times "make[1]: wx-config: Command not found". What am I doing wrong? I followed this tutorial to set up my basic project that still refuses to compile: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_CodeLite_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications

Comment: Did you try adding /usr/local/bin to your path as @VZ. suggested?

Comment: By calling echo $PATH I can see that /usr/local/wxwidgets is in my path, but at the same time if I call wx-config from my terminal it says   *** Error: Directory 'thepathofmypreviousattempt/wxWidgets-3.0.2/build-release/..'
             no longer exists.

Comment: What is `/usr/local/wxwidgets` doing in your path? `wx-config` is supposed to be installed in `/usr/local/bin`. Sorry but I have really no idea what have you done. My advice would be to start from scratch, undo all your changes and build and install wxWidgets normally. Absolutely nothing special should be needed.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for building and installing wxWidgets are included in the distribution and can also be viewed [online](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/osx/install.txt).

If your IDE doesn't find `wx-config`, you must not have the location where you installed it (`/usr/local/bin`) by default in your `PATH`. Add it there to fix this.

Comment: Shouldn't sudo make install do that?

Comment: `make install`, whether `sudo` or not, definitely doesn't modify your `PATH` and it would be pretty strange for it to do it.

Comment: But my current install IS in my PATH. By calling echo $PATH this is the output: /usr/local/wxwidgets:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin (where /usr/local/wxwidgets is my current install). Yet, calling wx-config gives me *** Error: Directory '/Users/luigigreco/Desktop/progetto-wx/wxWidgets-3.0.2/build-release/..'
             no longer exists., which is the old path. How can it be?

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested by VZ, you must change your PATH.

But not the variable PATH in your environment Windows but the variable PATH in your C++ project. It's strange but maybe it's different.

Go into (for eclipse) : 
C/C++Build->Environment->PATH (add the path of wx-config in the beginning).

Press : Apply, OK and build the project.

I think is strange that Eclipse don't update the PATH after rebooting the OS. Maybe we must add an option to Eclipse for building WxWidget and force Eclipse to update the PATH, but I don't know it.

This change work for me.

Eclipse / MinGW-MSYS / WxWidget 2.8